# I found this insect in Utah, USA. What is it?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I keep seeing this insect around my house. What is it?

[image]

Here is another [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9sxPXc4vq89TVd4dzVLTng5WDQ/view?usp=sharing):

Comment: A better pic would help. Keep this one for reference to the size, but could you post another?

Comment: sure. I may need to look for one again. let me see if I took a regular one.

Comment: ok The image is too high quality for me to load it here so I put a link to it right under the other image which is on this page.

Comment: This might not directly related to your question but as you found the animal inside your house you should REALLY make an effort to get rid of it. It can be a real plague and infest all your dry foodstuffs like cereals, pasta, nuts, ... !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks very much like the [Indian meal moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_mealmoth), *Plodia interpunctella*, to me. The size, morphology of the antenna and wing tips, and the pale band of scales are all fairly distinctive. (The proboscis isn't very clear in the photo below but it is in most other images you could find via Google; I just couldn't find a better one with a license allowing me to post it here.)

[image]
(Image by Kaldari (Own work) [Public domain], via Wikimedia Commons; URL https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Indianmeal_moth_2009.jpg)